# Gremlin-server health check endpoint for AWS ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, gremlin-server

Is there any HTTP/TCP endpoint for a gremlin-server health check? Currently, we are using the default TCP port but it doesn't seem to indicate the gremlin-server's health.

We noticed that gremlin-server crashed and was not running but the health check kept passing. We are using AWS Classic Load Balancer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you enabled an [HTTP endpoint for the Gremlin service](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_connecting_via_http)? The document above explains:

> While the default behavior for Gremlin Server is to provide a
>   WebSocket-based connection, it can also be configured to support plain
>   HTTP web service. The HTTP endpoint provides for a communication
>   protocol familiar to most developers, with a wide support of
>   programming languages, tools and libraries for accessing it.

If so, you can use an ELB HTTP health check to a target like this:

`HTTP:8182/?gremlin=100-1`

With a properly configured service, this query will return a 200 HTTP status code, which will indicate to the ELB that the service is healthy.

Comment: I have been following version 3.2.3 documentation which doesn't have websocket and http both option, that came out later in 3.2.6 I believe. I am using https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-janusgraph-storage-backend project which is currently on 3.2.3

But yes, that is exactly what I am looking for, thanks.